# How to search text in ios (with next and previous functionality)using phonegap ,jquery ,jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

can you please tell me how to search a text from page with next and previous functionality in query ,
I found lot of link But every link search all search at one time .But i need it search first word then using next and previous buttons to go next search text.
I found this
http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x8rpY/1/).

```
$('#searchfor').keyup(function(){
         var page = $('#all_text');
         var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
         var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
         var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");    
         var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");
         page.html(newHtml);
    });
```

This fiddle highlights all the found words on html.

I also have [this](https://github.com/nmartynenko/jquery-search-plugin) JQuery plugin, which has all your desired functions (Highlight, next/previous).

If it helps !